# how to close previous set interval when time is beyong its set time

Tags: javascript, html

I will be able to set two reminders using below code when session is about to expire. and it works fine. this is to ensure user is aware he is nearing session

```
        reminder1 = setTimeout(function(){alert("Hey, your session is ending")},360000);

        reminder2 = setTimeout(function(){
            redirect();
        },720000);

        function redirect(){
            document.location = "../logout.php"
        }
```

but when  user is beyond 360000  i dont want to display them. how do i clear those ? i know we have clear interval and is it the right way to do it ?

```
    setTimeout(function(){clearTimeout(reminder1),360001);
```

Comment: You need to look at setTimeout, not interval

Comment: Also what will allow them to stay after 720000 ?

Comment: See [the MDN page for `setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) (or any other reasonable reference). It will show keeping the handle and using [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval) to cancel it if desired. (Similarly, there's `clearTimeout` for `setTimeout`, though `clearTimeout` and `clearInterval` actually do the same thing, they don't care how you got the handle.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely wanted setTimeout all around

And NEVER use alert or prompt or confirm if you want a counter to continue. They are blocking

```js
const warning = document.getElementById("warning");
let reminder1, reminder2;

const red = function() {
  clearTimeout(reminder1)
  clearTimeout(reminder2)
  reminder1 = setTimeout(function() {
    console.log("redirecting")
    warning.classList.toggle("hide",true)  
    // redirect()
  }, 7200);
  reminder2 = setTimeout(function() {
    warning.classList.toggle("hide")
  }, 3600)
}
document.getElementById("stay").addEventListener("click",red)
red();
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<span id="warning" class="hide">Hey, your session is ending <button id="stay">Stay connected</button></span>
```